# groupby cumulative sum initial values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, cumsum

I have daily level stock return data that looks like:

```
df:
index           ID    Return
2016-01-04      A     0.01
2016-01-05      A     0.01
2016-01-06      A     0.02
...
2016-01-30      A     0.01
2016-02-02      A     0.05
...
2016-01-04      B     0.01
2016-01-05      B     0.01
...
```

I want to create a column of cumulative return for each stock within each month. Moreover, I want the first entry of each month to be 1 (in other words, the lag cumulative return up to the date), i.e.:

```
df:
index           ID    Return     Cum
2016-01-04      A     0.01        1 
2016-01-05      A     0.02       1.01
2016-01-06      A     0.03       1.03
...
2016-01-30      A     0.01       1.31
2016-02-02      A     0.05        1   
2016-02-03      A     0.01       1.05
...
2016-01-04      B     0.02        1
2016-01-05      B     0.01       1.02
```

So far what I did was to create a column 'ret_1' that is Return + 1 and use cumprod with groupby:

```
df['ret_1'] = df['Return'] + 1
cum = df.groupby(['ID', pd.Grouper(freq='M')])['ret_1'].cumprod()
```

However, this gives the CURRENT cumulative return, not the LAG cumulative return. I then used:

```
new_df = cum.shift(1, 'D')
```

This works for the dates in the middle, but it doesn't put a "1" for the beginning of each month (in fact, it completely erases the first entry of each month by shifting the entire index down by 1 day). It also creates an "extra" date for each month at the end, for example 2016-01-31 for stock A.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC

```
df['Cum']=df.groupby([df.ID,df.index.month]).Return.apply(lambda x : x.shift().fillna(0).add(1).cumprod()).values
df
Out[213]: 
           ID  Return   Cum
index                      
2016-01-04  A    0.01  1.00
2016-01-05  A    0.01  1.01
2016-01-06  A    0.02  1.02
2016-01-30  A    0.01  1.04
2016-02-02  A    0.05  1.00
2016-01-04  B    0.01  1.00
2016-01-05  B    0.01  1.01
```

Comment: if i have NaN in my original data, will this mess up results by filling all NaN with ones? is there a way i can just change the first entry of each month?

Comment: @ian_chan if you have NaN ,  cumsum will not work , you should fill as 0 firstly

Comment: thanks! i have a really large dataset and "apply" was taking forever to complete. but i think i solved the problem using the fillna() method you suggested. first i groupby ID and month, shift return and fillna(0), and then i again groupby ID and month and use cumsum on shifted return. it seems to be working.

Comment: but it failed when i tried two steps at once: groupby(ID and month).shift().fillna(0).cumsum(). The issue is that cumsum() does not return to 1 at the beginning of a new group, but continues from the last entry from the previous group. i dont know why...

Comment: @ian_chan chain function do not support , you need to do it within apply